# C# toolbar с возможностью "перетаскивания"

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, .net

Доброго времени суток!

Все мы знакомы с привычными элементами управления в графическом интерфейсе - toolbars (по-нашему "панели инструментов"). В windows forms этот элемент реализует класс: **System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip**. Стандартная функциональность тулбара - возможность его перетаскивания в любую область экрана (тогда он отображается как маленькое окно):
[image]
.

Вопрос в том, как осуществить описанное с помощью упомянутого класса **ToolStrip** и стандартным набором контролов windows forms (.net 3.5)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартными средствами ToolStrip/ToolStripContainer плавающие меню не реализуются. Их можно перемещать только из панели в панель. Нужно либо [переписать код](http://en.csharp-online.net/Tool%2C_Menu%2C_and_Status_Strips%E2%80%94Floating_ToolStrips) для ToolStrip, либо использовать [сторонний компонент](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/).

Comment: Спасибо. Практически то, что нужно.